# Electron vue : One Install overwriting another install

Tags: electron-vue

I created an application with electron-vue . I build it using yarn build and all. I was tasked with creating a second app which is very similar with few changes. I made the changes in a branch and changed name of app in package.json . But every time I install the second app on windows it is clearing out the first app that was installed earlier.

I tried updating name of app in package.json and App.vue and any other place I could think of. The final build name is different but everytime the second app is installed it seems to be building in same location as the first app and hence over-writing the first app not sure what am I doing wrong.

I cannot share the actual app due to some reasons. I however am sharing an empty skeleton . Please let me know what changes are required to make and I will try them out and update the template for future reference .

https://github.com/praveen2710/form-template

I was expecting I could use this template and install multiple apps in a single machine. As of now installing a second app over-writes the first app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that changing the [appId]
(https://github.com/praveen2710/form-template/blob/master/package.json#L26)
prevents the overwriting of the app during installation.